# Kafka as an Akka-persistence journal

Tags: apache-kafka, akka, akka-persistence

Among the different options of a write-journal to implement Event Sourcing, Kafka seems a very reasonable choice from "outside":

1. It has a great ecosystem
2. It is well documented
3. It naturally supports streaming and listeners

However, looking into Akka persistence, it appears that Kafka journal is supported only through a community contributed package, which has not been modified for the last 2 years. Is Kafka not a good option, are there better options and if it is the best option, how are people using it with akka-persistance?

Comment: There is an initiative to build an [akka.stream-based eventsourcing layer](https://github.com/krasserm/akka-stream-eventsourcing), which right now is able to cooperate with both akka.persistence and reactive-kafka as its event journal backends. In future eventuate should also be supported.

Comment: I see that, what I don't understand is why this is not the privileged choice?

Answer (score 4):

The problems with using Kafka as the event journal for akka-persistence (lack of atomic writes) are mentioned in this comment, which also lists it as a reason the plugin hasn't been maintained:
https://github.com/krasserm/akka-persistence-kafka/issues/28#issuecomment-138933868

In this thread, however, there is evidence that people are working on forks that work with latest kafka and akka versions:
https://github.com/krasserm/akka-persistence-kafka/issues/20

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look right [here](https://github.com/krasserm/akka-persistence-kafka/pull/37)

It's a pull request of the fork maintained right [here](https://github.com/worldline-messaging/akka-persistence-kafka/)

This version uses kafka 1.0 and the new producer API with transaction. We try to respect the best the akka persistence specification. We keep on with kafka because, for us, it is the best solution for event sourcing.